# C# XMLSerializer temp directory problems

Tags: c#, serialization, permissions

I have a C# console app invoked from a `SQL Server Agent job.`

The process runs as a network account I created.

Originally I got errors because the serializer ws trying to write to another user's temp directory (the account for the SQL Server Agent service itself), but I fixed that using the config setting

```
 <system.xml.serialization>
      <xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation="c:\\temp"/>
 </system.xml.serialization>
```

However now I get the error `"Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).`

```
error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\temp\2euqs4ou.dll' -- 'Access is denied. ' "
```

Both the accounts have full control over `c:\temp.`  I'm stumped.

I've been Googling this all day now with no success.  I am resisting making the service account a machine admin, but I will if I have to.

Comment: Is it possible that there are 2 instances of your EXE running and both trying to access that file concurrently?

Comment: How are you getting the consol app to run as a "Network Account I careted" from the SQLServer agent job ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not pre-generate the XmlSerializer assemblies with [sgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

> sgen.exe /assembly:MyFile.dll